# Error: Cannot find an overload for 'Init' that supplied arguments

Tags: swift

I am unable to fix this issue, I'm using Xcode6.

```
var numbersOnscreen:Double = 0;                 
        @IBOutlet var displabel: UILabel!

        @IBAction func numbers(sender: UIButton) {
            displabel.text = displabel.text + String(sender.tag-1)
            numbersOnscreen = Double(displabel.text)  //error line
        }
```

Comment: Check all involved variables and methods and lookup their types. What type has `displabel.text` ? Does `Double` have a corresponding init method?

Comment: displabel.text is an ui label  `@IBOutlet var displabel: UILabel!`

Comment: `displabel` is an `UILabel` – what type has `displabel.text` ?

Comment: `displabel.text` has type of String

Comment: sorry for late reply buddy

Comment: And now look again. `displabel.text` has the type `String?`, not `String`. Do you know the difference? Have you heard about "optionals" in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbersOnscreen = Double(displabel.text!)!
```

The `init` method you were calling expects a `String` (not an optional string):

```
struct Double {
    init?(_ text: String) { ... }
}
```

And keep in mind this is a *failable initializer* so another unwrapping (i.e., the last `!`) is needed as well.